# Input Button of type="image" is not working with href in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

```
<a href="javascript:OpenRuleEditor('@Url.Action("AddRule", "AdvancedRuleSearch", new { mode = "add" })','AddNewRule','Add New Rule')" style="text-decoration: none; display:inline-block">                          
    <input name="Plus" type="image" src="~/GHAimages/129.png" id="btnAddRule" title="Add New Rule"/>
</a>
```

By Clicking this Button it will open a new page. Button is basically a image button (Iconic which helps user to understand what they are doing exactly). Working fine in Firefox and Chrome. But in IE 11 it is not working. when I am changing its type from type="image" to type="button", it starts working, but it is not showing the image.

Also have tried with the following code, by putting it inside  tag.

```
onclick="window.location=this.parentNode.href;
```

Now, Image is showing on the button, button is working also and page is also opening but in the back side the window from which it has been invoked.

Any help is welcome..

Comment: Does it need to be a button? can it not just be an image tag?

Comment: If you say how to use then can try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  an `<img>` tag instead of an input tag.

```
<a href="javascript:OpenRuleEditor('@Url.Action("AddRule", "AdvancedRuleSearch", new { mode = "add" })','AddNewRule','Add New Rule')" style="text-decoration: none; display:inline-block">
    <img src="~/GHAimages/129.png"></img>
</a>
```

Also, I don't think you need a tilde in your path, try replacing `src="~/GHAimages/129.png"` with `src="/GHAimages/129.png"`. I would try this before using the image tag.

Comment: Thanks friend, it works for me successfully. Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

There is no valid reason to wrap an `<a href>` tag around an `input[type="image"]`.

Have you considered just using an `<img>`?